# Mysql query return values from "not in" clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a csv quoted string like this:

'800','002','786'

and in my table, I have:

```
 table: user
 id  username
 --  --------
 002 foofoo
```

how can I get mysql to return me the values that weren't found?  So I want the query to return me:

'800','786'

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Use `NOT IN` as you mentioned

Comment: `select * from my_table where id not in ('002');`

Comment: If `800` and `786` are not in the table, no query logic is going to find them. You can't select values that are not there. You can, however, select values *in the table* that are `NOT IN(x, y, z)`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "code", you should read values in the excel file. So you can form a String array. You can use the values in the array for your `NOT IN` query.

Simplified example with Java

```
    String [] excelArray;

    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            excelArray[counter] = cell.getStringCellValue();
        }
    }
```

Now you have the data you need in a data structure. So you can use the values in your `NOT IN` query.

```
    select * from my_table where id not in (myExcelArrayValues);

    if(queryReturnsNull) {
       print("There are no values with id's: " + allMyExcelArrayValues);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, sometimes the answer is just "you're an idiot and you can't do what you're trying to do"...  I ended up simply looping and checking each element...  I know an alternative could be to create a temp table/outer join, but my system doesn't allow me to do that :(

Thanks for the quick responses and I will try to do better about explaining in more detail in the future.

Thanks agan.